# How to remove html tags after compare to dispaly in ckeditor in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

In my web application i have to compare two documents and in Base document text is in html format i have anchor tag like this 
 `<a id="jobnumtext"><a name="jobnumtext" />` after compare this base document to another second document and i found the result i saw the anchor tag shows in ck editor like this `Job #: Anchor`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI4WE.png)  `red color strike through Anchor` when i see html code for this Anchor in compared text it shows

```
<span style='color:red'><s><span style='text-decoration:line-through'>Anchor
```

how can i disable this anchor in compared text(result text) it is displayed in ck editor

Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyhdL.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jquery you can use the `remove()` method to remove tags. You can see  examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp).

> `remove()` - Removes the selected element (and its child elements)

You just need to put the code in some function and run after comparing.

Comment: hi thank you for respond here i am getting `Anchor ` strike like this in text not in a tag.Could you please tell me how to replace or remove

Comment: I do not understand, you get only the text without tags?

Comment: I get text with tags only but i displayed text in ck editor and it is displayed based on html tags

Comment: Please, share a sample of your code to better understand.

Comment: hi, In my Base Document i don't have `Anchor` in text format like this it is in tag like this  `<a id="jobnumtext"><a name="jobnumtext" /><input type="text" value="sometext"/>` when i am comparing to another document it displayed in result document is `Anchor` line strike in red color i am attaching my image can you see above and displaying i am taking ck editor.

Comment: I got result text in &nbsp; letter and i remove like this for i am using this code `string CMText = dt.Rows[0]["ComparedText"].ToString();
    CMText = CMText.Replace("&amp;nbsp;", " ");` and like this how can i remove this 'Anchor'